# Is there a way to view the mobile version of a site in an iframe?

Tags: html

I’ve been trying for a while to create an iframe with the mobile version of my website. Even on a mobile device, the iframe always shows the desktop version. I searched Google for a while, but I couldn’t find any answers.

Comment: How do you differentiate between the two, just the viewport size?  Are you using something like Bootstrap to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using seamless and then setting the height and width:

```
seamless width="460" height="500"
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/jOqzQXe)

According to [W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp) it should not be supported but it seems to work fine:

Comment: @kakastia3819 Just be *very* careful using attributes that have been removed from the spec... you have no idea when a browser will drop support for it, so you need to monitor it regularly, and once one major browser does you’re back to square one looking for a solution again!

Comment: @FluffyKitten I don't think adding seamless actually effects anything.  I've tested Edge, Firefox and Chrome.  Seamless is supposed to make the iFrame appear and act like part of the parent.  i.e. no borders, scrollbars, the parent is redirected vs the iFrame, etc. according to the initially proposed [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-seamless).  I think it's really just the size of the iFrame having a smaller size which forces their mobile layout.